# How to ServerSignature Off and ServerTokens Prod from NGINX?

Tags: nginx

I want to hide the information detail about nginx or infromation details from Reverse Proxy ? 
i have to add `server_tokens off;` between `http` tag from `nginx.conf`

Console output when i tried to get information nginx with curl below

`curl -I https://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 15 May 2017 09:25:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SameOrigin
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=1000; includeSubDomains
Content-Language: en`

Answer (score 0):

Directive:
`server_tokens off` hides only version of nginx. If you want to change header `Server: nginx` you need to use additional nginx module "Headers More", available for example in packet nginx-extras (Debian, Ubuntu).
Then you can use for example:

```
server_tokens off; 
more_set_headers "Server: IIS";
```

If you really want to hide server engine, you should also change error sites.

Comment: Hi @Jack this is installed from windows, how to use nginx module "Headers More" for windows ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'don know how nginx can be installed on windows and how to find version with additional modules (like "Headers More Module").